# tikz pgf-umlsd margin in the diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, pgf-umlsd

Is there any way to control the margin within a tikz pgf-umlsd diagram?

I'm using the following code and could already remove the indent by using `\noindent`. But still there is some unused space to the left within the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\noindent%
\fbox{%
\begin{sequencediagram}%
    \newthread{client}{Some Client}
    \newinst{server}{Some Server}
    \newinst{third}{Some Third Service}
    \begin{call}{client}{do}{server}{}
    \end{call}
    \begin{messcall}{server}{notify}{third}
    \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}%
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** To follow the community rules, I've replaced my code example by a compiling MWE. The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFgzj.png) of my original example is still available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFgzj.png), if you also want to see the code, please take a look in the edit history of this question.

Comment: With `\resizebox{w}{h}{content}` from `graphicx` at leased its possible to keep the diagram within the column, but still the margin is there and its no 100% nice solution.

Comment: ***Careless line ending costs lives!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that the package code does not take care to avoid the introduction of spurious spaces. This is a bug and should be fixed.

Normally, I'd suggest patching the relevant commands. However, I'm not sure how to patch something like

```
\newenvironment{sequencediagram}{
```

so that we get

```
\newenvironment{sequencediagram}{%
```

In any case, a ***lot** of patches would be required. At least 5 `%` are required in the first 5 lines of the definition of `sequencediagram`.

It is possible to simply replace the definition with a new one. The following fixes the spacing problem (and updates the syntax for TikZ 3.0):

```
\renewenvironment{sequencediagram}{%
  % declare layers
  \pgfdeclarelayer{umlsd@background}%
  \pgfdeclarelayer{umlsd@threadlayer}%
  \pgfsetlayers{umlsd@background,umlsd@threadlayer,main}%
%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      sequence/.style={coordinate},
      inststyle/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=west, minimum height=0.8cm, minimum width=1.6cm, fill=white, drop shadow={opacity=1,fill=black}},
      blockstyle/.style={anchor=north west},
      blockcommentstyle/.style={anchor=north west, font=\small},
      dot/.style={inner sep=0pt,fill=black,circle,minimum size=0.2pt},
    ]
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \ifpgfumlsdroundedcorners
    \tikzset{%
      inststyle/.style+={rounded corners=3mm}}
    \fi
    \global\def\unitfactor{0.6}
    \global\def\threadbias{center}
    % reset counters
    \setcounter{preinst}{0}
    \setcounter{instnum}{0}
    \setcounter{threadnum}{0}
    \setcounter{seqlevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callselflevel}{0}
    \setcounter{blocklevel}{0}

    % origin
    \node[coordinate] (inst0) {};
}{
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{umlsd@background}
    \ifnum\c@instnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\theinstnum}{
      \draw[dotted] (inst\t) -- ++(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-2.2*\unitfactor);
    }
    \fi
    \ifnum\c@threadnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\thethreadnum}{
      \path (thread\t)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.1*\unitfactor) node (threadend) {};
      \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[threadcolor\t]
      \drawthread{thread\t}{threadend}
    }
    \fi
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

This helps, but it does not completely eliminate the problem because spaces are presumably being introduced by the commands within the `sequencediagram` environment as well. If I use an empty environment, I now get a box as large as if I'd just made an empty `\fbox{}` with no content. But once I replace the content, I get some spurious space again:

[image: improved spacing for environment with spurious spaces remaining on left]

To fix this, you'd need to patch or redefine all of the relevant macros to remove the spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{sequencediagram}{%
  % declare layers
  \pgfdeclarelayer{umlsd@background}%
  \pgfdeclarelayer{umlsd@threadlayer}%
  \pgfsetlayers{umlsd@background,umlsd@threadlayer,main}%
%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      sequence/.style={coordinate},
      inststyle/.style={rectangle, draw, anchor=west, minimum height=0.8cm, minimum width=1.6cm, fill=white, drop shadow={opacity=1,fill=black}},
      blockstyle/.style={anchor=north west},
      blockcommentstyle/.style={anchor=north west, font=\small},
      dot/.style={inner sep=0pt,fill=black,circle,minimum size=0.2pt},
    ]
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \ifpgfumlsdroundedcorners
    \tikzset{%
      inststyle/.style+={rounded corners=3mm}}
    \fi
    \global\def\unitfactor{0.6}
    \global\def\threadbias{center}
    % reset counters
    \setcounter{preinst}{0}
    \setcounter{instnum}{0}
    \setcounter{threadnum}{0}
    \setcounter{seqlevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callselflevel}{0}
    \setcounter{blocklevel}{0}

    % origin
    \node[coordinate] (inst0) {};
}{
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{umlsd@background}
    \ifnum\c@instnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\theinstnum}{
      \draw[dotted] (inst\t) -- ++(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-2.2*\unitfactor);
    }
    \fi
    \ifnum\c@threadnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\thethreadnum}{
      \path (thread\t)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.1*\unitfactor) node (threadend) {};
      \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[threadcolor\t]
      \drawthread{thread\t}{threadend}
    }
    \fi
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\noindent%
\fbox{%
\begin{sequencediagram}%
  \newthread{client}{Some Client}
  \newinst{server}{Some Server}
  \newinst{third}{Some Third Service}
  \begin{call}{client}{do}{server}{}
  \end{call}
  \begin{messcall}{server}{notify}{third}
  \end{messcall}
\end{sequencediagram}%
}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Presumably egreg's package could patch this without needing to overwrite the environment, but the warning on that package makes me reluctant to dabble myself - let alone impose such dabbling on innocent bystanders.

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to prepare a new release of this package, including this fix? There are quite some forks of the original google code project on github, don't know, which one is authoritative.

Comment: I think the remaining space it caused by the fact, that `\newinst`has a default edge distance of `[0.2]`, while `\newinst` is called from `\newthread` at the beginning.

Comment: @white_gecko Really, this should be reported to the current maintainer of the package so that the version on CTAN gets corrected. This is clearly a bug and it is not difficult to fix - just a question, mostly, of adding comment signs at the end of lines when required.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to patch the `sequencediagram` environment.

It is not very nice and will break once the original package is fixed, *but* you only have to add a few lines now and only will only have to remove them then ;-)

Add the following before `\begin{document}`:

```
\let\oldsequencediagram\sequencediagram
\let\oldendsequencediagram\endsequencediagram
\renewenvironment{sequencediagram}{%
    \hspace*{-7.8mm}\oldsequencediagram%
}{%
    \oldendsequencediagram\hspace*{-.5mm}%
}
```

**Note**: I found these values via trial and error. Maybe it is more clever to specify the negative space using other units. In my document, I use a left space of `-8.6mm`.